# Edit triangulation

Tags: modeling

In 3dsMax I can edit the triangulation for every Ngon separately. After I leave the "Edit Tri."-setting I can keep working with the Ngon. Is there a way to do the same in Blender?

[image]

Comment: Nope, but apart from selecting one face vs multiple faces, what other benefits do you seek?`

Comment: A clean looking mesh in planar areas.